# Tuple matching vs. variable assignment in Python

Tags: python

I always thought that tuple matching was the same as variable assignment, so I thought these two pieces of code did the same thing:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

and

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

However, that has not been the case in the following two pieces of code that give me different outputs:

```
def fib(seq_len):
    a = 1
    b = 1
    sequence = []
    for i in range(seq_len):
        sequence.append(a)
        a, b = b, a + b
    return sequence

fib(10)
```

which gives the output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

and

```
def fib(seq_len):
    a = 1
    b = 1
    sequence = []
    for i in range(seq_len):
        sequence.append(a)
        a = b
        b = a + b
    return sequence

fib(10)
```

which gives the following output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
```

It seems that in the first definition of `fib`, the previous value of `a` is being used for `a, b = b, a + b` but I don't understand how it remembers that previous value because we have assigned `a` to another value i.e. `b` before moving on to `b = a + b`

Comment: The entire right-hand side is evaluated before either assignment is made. In your second code, you modify `a` before `a + b` gets evaluated.

Comment: You have not reassigned `a` to anything else before line `a, b = b, a + b`. In this case, it still takes the value of the previous iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a, b = b, a + b` is equivalent to

```
t = b, a + b
a, b = t
```

not

```
a = b
b = a + b  # essentially, b = 2 * b
```

The right-hand side must be fully evaluated before you perform either assignment.

Comment: Note that there can be rare cases where the behavior goes weird. The left-hand side is assigned from left to right, so something like `a, seq[a] = ...` will use the new value of `a` to index `seq`, while `seq[a], a = ...` will use the old value of `a`. By contrast, excepting weird side-effect cases (from function/method calls, the new walrus operator, etc.), the load order on the right-hand side doesn't matter, since it only reads, it doesn't write the left-hand side at all until the whole `tuple` is constructed.

Comment: @ShadowRanger True. Code like that is stuff I would start flagging in a code review :)